# Converting Transparent Image to Black background changes colors

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bxRg.png) Image with a transparent background. I want to convert the transparent background to solid black. I do not want to change the color of any pixels in the logo.

I use the following code for this:

```
image = Image.open(IMG_PATH)
new_image = Image.new("RGBA", image.size, "BLACK") # Create a white rgba background
new_image.paste(image, (0, 0), image)              # Paste the image on the background. 
new_image.convert('RGB').save(SAVE_PATH, "PNG")  # Save as PNG
```

But the result looks like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rglsd.png) image. Though I got black background instead of transparent, If you notice, the logo colors are a bit dull now. Why is this happening? How to prevent this? I want my Image to be in the same color as in the original one, but the background should be Black. I am open to use any other libraries like Opencv also.

UPDATE:

Result generated by Photoshop : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rglsd.png)

Result generated by above code : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOw79.jpg)

There is a visible difference in both Images above.

Comment: Is the original logo partially transparent?  Also could this just be an optical illusion?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checker_shadow_illusion

Comment: I don't know what you exactly mean by "Partially transparent", but all part except the "adidas" and the 3 trapezoids are transparent. Initially I too thought that Its an Illusion, but later when I tried to do the same in Photoshop, I got different result. Please check the updated post.

Comment: The image (the white part) is partially transparent. Doing a quick test in the console and changing the background colour to red turns the logo pinkish.

Answer (score 1):

Fill transparent area with color using OpenCV:

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

dir = sys.path[0]
im = cv2.imread(dir+'/im.png', -1)
im[np.where(im[:, :, 3] == 0)] = (0, 0, 0, 255)
cv2.imwrite(dir+'/im_.png', im)
```

Testcase for sure:

[image]

Fill anywhere not fully transparent:

```py
im[np.where(im[:, :, 3] != 0)] = (0, 0, 0, 255)
```

[image]

Fill in anywhere that is transparent or has alpha:

```py
im[np.where(im[:, :, 3] != 0|255)] = (0, 0, 0, 255)
```

[image]

Fill anywhere without alpha channel:

```py
im[np.where(im[:, :, 3] == 0|255)] = (0, 0, 0, 255)
```

[image]